# Eclipse on Ubuntu: How do I access projects remotely over mounted SFTP connections?

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, sftp

Ubuntu allows you to create and "bookmark" connections to other servers via either Public FTP or SSH. I want to work with projects on a remote server this way. However when I attempt to create a project, I cannot browse to the bookmarked connection; it does not show up in the explorer window.

Truth is, I know I've done this in the past, but I don't remember how I did it and can't find anything via Google that looks quite right. Was it a special Eclipse plugin, perhaps?

How do I get Eclipse to recognize and display those bookmarked connections in the explorer window?

Comment: Looking for the same answer. Did you find out how?

Comment: For something so simple, you'd think a solution would be out there. Anyone?

Comment: Wow, I really was looking for the name of the plugin, or the simplest *confirmed* accurate method.. instead I've mainly got vague answers and guesses. I guess I'll have to go with salva's solution, though it seems more complicated than what I've done in the past.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `sshfs` to mount the remote directory containing the project:

```
$ mkdir -p ~/mnt/foo
$ sshfs remote_host:/path/to/dir ~/mnt/foo
$ cd ~/mnt/foo
$ ls
```

**update**:

Recent Gnome releases made the remote shares available via a [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/) file system (`gvfs-fuse`) under `$HOME/.gvfs/`.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how I would make use of the FUSE filesystem to display these bookmarks in Eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to make a symbolic link (*symlink*) to your bookmarked connection in your home folder. That's how I manage to fix the problem in most applications wich are using a non-GTK file explorer.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you cannot reuse the GNOME bookmarks in Eclipse, as it provides its own file system layer.

However, the [Remote System Explorer](http://www.eclipse.org/tm/) framework allows creating remote locations you could use in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

I think eclipse has an ssh plugin which you can use. I dont remember clearly, its been quite some time since I used eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the directory mounted in ~/.gvfs.